# How can I use std::reference_wrapper as a class member?

Tags: c++

I use a library that only returns references to created objects `Entity& Create(int id)`. In my class, I need to create one of these and store it.

I had thought to use class member `std::reference_wrapper<Entity> MyClass::m_Entity` but the problem is, I would like to create this object in a call to a method like `MyClass::InitEntity()` – so I run into a compile error "no default constructor available" because `m_Entity` is not initialised in my constructor.

Is there any way around this, other than to change my class design? Or is this a case where using pointers would make more sense?

Comment: Does it make sense for `MyClass` to *not* have a reference to an `Entity` at all times? In other words, is `MyClass` in a valid state before calling `InitEntity()`? If it is, use a pointer. If it isn't, get rid of `InitEntity()` and do the work in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Is `MyClass` in a valid state if it doesn't have a valid reference to an `Entity`? If it is, then you should use a pointer. The constructor initializes the pointer to `nullptr`, and the `InitEntity` function assigns it to the address of a valid `Entity` object.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(): _entity(nullptr) {}
    void InitEntity() { _entity = &Create(123); }
    void doSomethingWithEntity()
    {
        if (_entity) ...
    }

private:
    Entity *_entity;
};
```

If `MyClass` *isn't* in a valid state without a valid reference to an `Entity`, then you can use a `std::reference_wrapper<Entity>` and initialize it in the constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(): _entity(Create(123)) {}
    void doSomethingWithEntity()
    {
        ...
    }

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<Entity> _entity;
};
```

Of course which one you go with depends on how `MyClass` is supposed to be used. Personally, the interface for `std::reference_wrapper` is a little awkward for me, so I'd use a pointer in the second case as well (while still ensuring that it's always not null).

Comment: It's just a shame you have to put everything in your ctor, can end up somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: @Mr.Boy You could use the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to construct the object over time while still ensuring that the object you get is never in an intermediate or invalid state.

Comment: Also, a minor benefit of using a pointer in the 2nd case is that you can assign the pointer in the body of the constructor rather than in the initializer list.